# TextBox.IsLoaded returns False after it is visible

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, internals

In a `DataGrid` I use `CellTemplate` and `CellEditingTemplate`. In both DataTemplates [FrameworkElement.IsLoaded Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.isloaded.aspx) returns `False` even if I can see the `TextBlock`, use the `TextBox` and `Focus()` call has returned `True`.

Is this a bug? Or could someone explain, what's the reason for this behaviour?

---

*I've created this sample application for demonstration purposes.*

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new List<string> { "Row1", "Row2" };
        }
    }

    public class FocusAttached
    {
        public static bool GetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty =
             DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsFocused", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsFocusedChanged));

        static void IsFocusedChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = obj as FrameworkElement;

            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                Console.Write(element);
                Console.Write("  IsLoaded=" + element.IsLoaded);
                Console.Write("  IsVisible=" + element.IsVisible);
                Console.Write("  Focusable=" + element.Focusable);
                // here I call Focus()
                Console.Write("  Focus() returns:" + element.Focus());
                Console.WriteLine("  IsLoaded=" + element.IsLoaded);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
        Title="Please click on row!" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsLoaded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay,
                                                  StringFormat='TextBlock in CellTemplate: IsLoaded={0}'}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox c:FocusAttached.IsFocused="True"
                                 Text="{Binding IsLoaded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay,
                                                StringFormat='Even after call Focus(): IsLoaded={0}'}" />                                     
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>            
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your bindings are useless, because IsLoaded is not a dependency property. There are no notifications, there are no changes of Text.

IsLoaded is false, because it is deferred like measurement and arrangement. The element is focusable, visible, and enabled, so it can be focused. But there is no guarantee that element already measured and rendered at this point. These actions enqueued in Dispatcher. When they'll be processed, IsLoaded will be true. Try this:

```
static void IsFocusedChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement element = obj as FrameworkElement;

    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
    {
        Console.Write(element);
        Console.Write("  IsLoaded=" + element.IsLoaded);
        Console.Write("  IsVisible=" + element.IsVisible);
        Console.Write("  Focusable=" + element.Focusable);
        // here I call Focus() 
        Console.Write("  Focus() returns:" + element.Focus());
        element.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  IsLoaded=" + element.IsLoaded);
            }),
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, then IsLoaded is True and your right about the Binding. But this means you can focus an element even if it's not yet (or maybe never) integrated into the presentation engine (`IsLoaded=True`)? And `IsVisible=True` doesn't mean you can truly see the element?

Comment: The trouble here is that you trying to compare different processes with different nature. IsLoaded is a part of measure/arrange/render mechanism while the focus is a part of application logic. Is the element valid for focus? Yes, it is, because it's enabled and visible, and it is attached to PresentationSource (because Template was realized). Is the element already loaded? Not yet, but it will, because it is attached to PresentationSource.